# how to pass a parameter in workflow expression editor in informatica powercenter workflow manager?

Tags: date, parameters, informatica

I have ETL job that runs on oracle database every month.
Instead of writing hard coded dates in every sql query I' ve created parameter file
which returns last day of last 2 months that I used in other sessions.
for example, If I run this session today(06.01.2023) it should return '05.31.2023' and '04.30.2023'

The query for dates is below:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(RUN_DATE,'DD.MM.YYYY') AS  RUN_DATE_V,
TO_CHAR(TRUNC(RUN_DATE,'MM')-1,'DD.MM.YYYY') AS LAST_DAY_PREV_MONTH_V,
TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(RUN_DATE,'MM'),-2)),'DD.MM.YYYY') LAST_DAY_2_PREV_MONTH_V
FROM (SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) AS RUN_DATE FROM DUAL ) P
```

the parameter string is below:

```
'[Global]'||chr(10)||
'$$FolderName='||$PMFolderName||chr(10)||
'$$RUN_DATE='||RUN_DATE_V||chr(10)||
'$$LAST_DAY_PREV_MONTH='||LAST_DAY_PREV_MONTH_V||chr(10)||
'$$LAST_DAY_2_PREV_MONTH='||LAST_DAY_2_PREV_MONTH_V||chr(10)||
'FILE_CREATE_TIME='|| SYSDATE
```

the session' s result is:

```
[Global]
$$FolderName=xxx
$$RUN_DATE=01.06.2023
$$LAST_DAY_PREV_MONTH=31.05.2023
$$LAST_DAY_2_PREV_MONTH=30.04.2023
FILE_CREATE_TIME=06/01/2023 10:36:13.000000
```

When this session runs and completes it raises a flag and other depended session starts to run.

for the reasons I could not find out, sometimes thedates returned are just wrong, instead of last day of May, it returns last day of april.
This leads to wrong results in other sessions.
What I want to do is to put some sort of control mechanism. If last day of previous month is wrong date it should not raise a flag.

In the powercenter workflow  manager screen, I have tried to use expression editor by writing to_date('$$LAST_DAY_PREV_MONTH','dd.mm.yyyy')=add_to_date(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1).
It returns invalid date value string. I have tried it without quotes, dollar signs,"to_date function" nothing worked
I thing I cannot use mapping parameter here.
Is there way to this?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a potential issue related to time zones. Here is a possible scenario to consider:

- The workflow is scheduled to run on the **1st of July** at **2:30 AM**.
- The Integration Service, located in `A`, initiates the workflow.
- A query is sent to the database located in `B`, with a time zone adjustment of `A - 3 hours`. As a result, the time recorded in the query is **June 31st, 11:30 PM**.
- The function `LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(RUN_DATE,'MM'),-2))` is used to determine the last day of the current month, subtracting 2 months. However, the calculation is based on the time of the database server, resulting in **April 30th** instead of the expected **May 31st**.

This is just a hypothesis. Please verify and compare the location, time zone, and time settings between your Integration Service and the Database Server to confirm if this is the underlying cause.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Actually I found out the reason why parameter date came out wrong, during the the deletion of  the old and creation and rasing the flag for new parameter file, the other sessions already started reading the existing file. That being the case, I still cannot find how to control if the parameter dates are correct or not.